# Is it possible to use groupBy with a "with" function in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I am trying to use groupBy with Laravel's with function. Here is my query

```
$msgs=Conversation::where('sender', $sender)
    ->orWhere('reciever', $sender)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->with('message')
    ->get();
```

This query returns many records from the message table but I want to retrieve only one.

This is data and I want to group the result from the message object

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": 27,
        "sender": 10,
        "reciever": 4,
        "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:04",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:04",
        "message": [
            {
                "id": 5,
                "conversation_id": 27,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "5",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:04",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:04"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "conversation_id": 27,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "6",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:19",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:19"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "conversation_id": 27,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "7",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:35",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:35"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "conversation_id": 27,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "8",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:36",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:46:36"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 26,
        "sender": 10,
        "reciever": 7,
        "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:40:02",
        "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:40:02",
        "message": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "conversation_id": 26,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "1",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:40:02",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:40:02"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "conversation_id": 26,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "2",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:36",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:36"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "conversation_id": 26,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "3",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:50",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:50"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "conversation_id": 26,
                "last_sender": 10,
                "msg": "4",
                "deleted": null,
                "seen": null,
                "created_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:57",
                "updated_at": "2017-07-26 22:45:57"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Any help is highly appreciated. Let me know if things are not clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of 'with' replace it with this:

```
$msgs=Conversation::where('sender', $sender)
    ->orWhere('reciever', $sender)
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->with(['message'  => function ($query) { return $query->first();}])
    ->get();
```

this will return only one "message" instead of a collection of messages.
you can inside the callback function apply whatever whether it is (pluck, select,take...etc)

Comment: Thank you for the help. But this is not what I want. This query is limiting to 1 but I want to group the results. You will better understand may be if you see the query "string(93) "select * from `conversations` where `sender` = ? or `reciever` = ? order by `created_at` desc"
string(104) "select * from `messages` where `messages`.`conversation_id` in (?, ?) order by `created_at` desc limit 1"
string(104) "select * from `messages` where `messages`.`conversation_id` in (?, ?) order by `created_at` desc limit 1""

Comment: I guess I got it, so like I said you can apply whatever inside the  callback, you can do as follow:
`->with(['message'  => function ($query) { 
return $query->whereIn('conversation_id',['value1','value2'])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();`
}])

Comment: Thanks again. But no luck. This is what I used 
"Conversation::where('sender', $sender)
        ->orWhere('reciever', $sender)
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->with(['message' => function ($query) { 
             $query->whereIn('conversation_id',['msg','seen']);
        }])->get();"

It doesn't give any value for message object.. 

One thing I noticed, I can use almost anything but cannot use  groupBy in the callback.

Comment: it looks weird doing whereIn('conversation_id',['msg','seen']); }]) and id that has "seen" or "msg" but the thing u can do to debug this,
is try to retrieve only the messages, in a separate query if it works then add it to the callback inside "with"